# Oracle database query

Tags: oracle

I would like to create a test database table which contains 1 million random records. As I am new to database ,
is there any way to populate it with any script?

Here is my query for my table.

```
CREATE TABLE Employee (SEQNUM NUMBER,
                       START_DATE DATE,
                       END_DATE DATE,
                       DURATION TIME,
                       START_TIME TIME,
                       END_TIME TIME,
                       TOTAL_NUM NUMBER);
```

Comment: You should not separate date and time portion. Data type `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` contains always both, date and time value.

Comment: There is no `TIME` data type in Oracle. I suggest your table should be `CREATE TABLE Employee (SEQNUM NUMBER, START_DATE DATE, END_DATE DATE, DURATION INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND, TOTAL_NUM NUMBER)`. Best of luck.

Comment: I have a hard time imagining what the "duration" of an Employee is.

Comment: If Duration is the difference between end_date and start_date, it shouldn't be stored in the DB - that's one of the principles of proper DB design. QUESTION: What kind of number should TOTAL_NUM be? An integer? Limited to a low and a high value? Non-negative?

Comment: It is just a sample table so i just put the basic name as Employee. Actually i am creating a table for storing Call Detail Records(CDR). Thanks  @WernfriedDomscheit  and  mathguy  for quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Here a simple query to get sample data using the dual table and DBMS_RANDOM.

```
CREATE TABLE SMPL 
AS                        
WITH 
    smpl AS 
(                       
    SELECT 
        ROWNUM SEQNUM,
        TO_DATE('01012016','ddmmyyyy') + 365 * dbms_random.value START_TIME, /* random 1 year timestamps from 1.1.2016 */
        TRUNC(10000 * dbms_random.value) TOTAL_NUM, /* random 0 .. 10.000 */
        31 * dbms_random.value DURATION /* duration 0 .. 31 days */
    FROM dual 
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 100  /* update number of records here */
)
SELECT 
    SEQNUM, 
    TRUNC(START_TIME) START_DATE,
    TRUNC(START_TIME + DURATION) END_DATE,
    DURATION,
    START_TIME,
    START_TIME + DURATION END_TIME,
    TOTAL_NUM
FROM smpl;
```

As other noted the `EMPLOYEE` is not the right name. Also consider to store only

`START_TIME` and `DURATION` physically in teh table and calculate (e.g. in a view) the dependent columns `START_DATE`, `END_TIME`, `END_DATE`.

Comment: And here is an edit to show how to also indent a query.

Comment: Thanks @Marmite Bomber for the quick solution. Yes the table name is bit weird , I didn't think of changing name as its just a sample table. The query works perfect again thanks for the solution.